# How do I interpret following equations on fibonacii numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, fibonacci-numbers, recursion

I went through an online tutorial (http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/14385) on finding n-th fibonacci number which explains a method as,

> You are standing at position n in Ox axis.
>
> In a step, you can move to the left 1 or 2. How many ways to reach position $0$?
>
> It is not hard to realize $f(n) = f(n - 1) + f(n - 2) $ with $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=1$. Therefore $ f(n)$ is $(n+1)th $ element in fibonacci sequence.
>
> **There are two cases**:
>
> **1. $n=2k$**
>
> we have two choices:
>
> first choice is to jump from $2k$ to $k$ and jump to $0$,
>
> another choice is to jump from $ n $ to $ k+1 $, *move 2 step left*, and jump from $ k-1 $ to 0. 
>   Therefore,$$ f(2k) = f(k)\cdot f(k) + f(k-1)\cdot f(k-1) \tag{1}$$
>
> **2. $n=2k+1$:**
>
> consider two segments $0..k$ and $k..n$.
>
> There are two choices: first choice is to jump from  $n$ to $k$ and jump from $k$ to $0$,
>   another choice is to jump from $n$ to $k+1$, *move 2 steps to the left*, and
>   jump from $k-1$ to $0$.
>
> Therefore, $$ f(2k+1) = f(k)\cdot f(k+1) + f(k-1)\cdot f(k). \tag{2}$$

I am not getting how the eq. $(1)$ and $(2)$ are written although I understand that each equation represent combination of two cases but why aren't the steps(italicized) considered while forming the equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider the case $n=2k$. Moving from $n$ to $0$ you have two disjoint cases: 1) you will stop at $k$ or 2) you will not stop at $k$.

1) You have $f(k)$ ways to arrive at $k$ and $f(k)$ ways to arrive at $0$ from $k$. Hence you get a total of $f(k)\cdot f(k)$ cases.

2) If you will not stop at $k$, since you can move left 1 or 2, you have to stop at $k+1$ (you can not jump more than 2 positions). So you have $f(k-1)$ ways to arrive at $k+1$. Then you take a step 2 and arrive at $k-1$ and finally in $f(k-1)$ ways you arrive at $0$. Hence you get a total of  $f(k-1)\cdot f(k-1)$ cases.

A similar argument works for $n=2k+1$.

P.S. You can take a look at [Example 2.4](https://www.whitman.edu/Documents/Academics/Mathematics/Jenne.pdf) (pdf file). There is a similar combinatorial proof of the identity $f(m+n)=f(m)f(n)+f(m-1)f(n-1)$.

Comment: I took a look on that example and understood the no of ways of tiling dominoes and squares there but I'm not able to correlate  those ways with  and no. of ways here from jumping x..to..y.. Can you please help me a bit more

Comment: Start with the empty tiling and add the new pieces on the left.
Moving 1 to the left is like putting one square in the tiling.
Moving 2 to the left  is like putting a domino in the tiling.